# Merging lines in Notepad++ or by using Python

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I have a long file which is structured like below:

- every line should start with `500`
- there are lines not starting with `500` (Line 2, Line 4, basically every even line)

What I want to do:

- The lines not starting with `500` should be merged with not even line above (so Line 2 with Line 1, Line 4 with Line 3, etc).
- Once merging additional semicolon should be added (i.e. `<Line 1>;<Line 2>`).

How I can easily do it in python (2.7)?

Regex in **Notepad++** may also work. I've heard that I should use a multi-line mode but I don't know how to do it. Probably it's not even hard but I have a hard time dealing with it.

Thanks.

Here the input (simplified):

```
;500;616;;”YPO_INV”;”KP”;”51D0072”;”YNU”
;”     6,291.00”;;
;500;6900;;”YPNV”;”KE”;”53213072”;”YOU”
;”     6,991.00”;;
```

[image: screenshot Notepad++]

Expected output:

```
;500;616;;”YPO_INV”;”KP”;”51D0072”;”YNU”;;”     6,291.00”;;
;500;6900;;”YPNV”;”KE”;”53213072”;”YOU”;;”     6,991.00”;;
```

Comment: How come all answers go a Downvote??

Comment: top `5%` downvoters should ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[\r\n]+(?!;500)
```

Replace each match with a `;`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC0DuR/1/)**

**Explanation:**

- `[\r\n]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of either a newline character or a carriage return
- `(?!;500)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current position is not followed by `:500`

**Before Replacing:**

[image]

**After replacing:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`\n^(?!;500)`](https://regex101.com/r/vA16Pt/2)

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `(?!)` Negative Lookahead

**Python code**:

```
text = open(r'C:\....txt').read()
r = re.compile(r'\n^(?!;500)', re.M)
text = r.sub(';', text)
```

Output:

```
;500;616;;”YPO_INV”;”KP”;”51D0072”;”YNU”;;”     6,291.00”;;
;500;6900;;”YPNV”;”KE”;”53213072”;”YOU”;;”     6,991.00”;;
```

[Demo code](https://ideone.com/hbTGeV)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Notepad++` for this kind of simple changes.

1. Go to **Replace** menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
2. Select **Regular expressions** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
3. Enter following values:

   - *Find what*: `[\r\n]+(;(?!500))`
   - *Replace with*: `\1`
4. Click on **Replace All** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)